# three exactly same if statement tests but the third one fails JAVA

Tags: java

Why my if statement returns true on two tests but fails the third even though its the same as test 2. 
Im trying to make a basic basketball scoreboard. 
I used three lines of

```
scoreboard2.homeGoal(3);
```

to set the total points to be 9 but the third one keeps returning a false statement. The if statement only allows there to be a total of 6 points.

```
public boolean homeGoal(int points) {
    boolean success = true;
    if (mHomePoints >= 0 && mHomePoints < 4) {
        mHomePoints = mHomePoints + points;
    } else {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: offtopic: can you score 0 points in that sport??

Comment: `The if statement only allows there to be a total of 6 points` ... no, the `if` statement only increments `mHomePoints` if is between 0 and 3.

Comment: The code isn't terrible, but you should also show the code which is calling your method.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, can you explain how?

Comment: Please post the complete class with your test.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the scoreboard.homeGoal(3); is the one that is calling the method

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `mHomePoints >= 0 && mHomePoints < 4` means 0, 1, 2, and 3

Comment: @IndraBasak the one with all the methods? or the one that is calling the methods?

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem. Include complete sequence of calls, actual and expected result.

Comment: @Pop1920 Post your test - the one which is calling `homeGoal`

Comment: i just needed to use points instead of mHomePoints in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mHomePoints` is initially 0, calling `homeGoal(3)` three times will:

1. update `mHomePoints` to 3 and return `true`
2. update `mHomePoints` to 6 and return `true`
3. return `false`

The exact same call generates 3 different results, because the method is [**stateful**](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/stateless).

Answer (score 0):

> ***Why my if statement returns true on two tests but fails the third...***

because you have an ill-defined logic here `mHomePoints >= 0 && mHomePoints < 4`

and as soon as the score stored in `mHomePoints` is higher than 3 the method will return false...

Comment: should it be an || statement instead of &&

Comment: what is the goal of that method..??

Comment: the goal of the method was to be able to add points so on the score board it would show the amount of points scored by that team

Comment: @Pop1920 all numbers are both >= 0 or < 4 so || would make the statement always true

Comment: @slipperyseal  I worked that out it was the mHomePoints in the if statement that was wrong, it needed to be points instead

Comment: @Pop1920 ahh i see

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out, instead of  `if(mHomepoints)` it should be `if(points)`.

```
public boolean homeGoal(int points) {
    boolean success = true;
    if (mHomePoints >= 0 && mHomePoints < 4) {
        mHomePoints = mHomePoints + points;
    } else {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;

}
```

Thank you all for your help.